# Chrome browser not displaying background image?

Tags: css, google-chrome, background

I have created a background image of diagonal lines using CSS. Here is the code i am using for chrome:

```
 #body-news {   
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 45%, #9CC 45%, #9CC  50%, #fff 50%, #fff 95%, #9CC 95%);
 background-size: 7px 7px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;}
```

This works in all other browsers but not chrome. You can view it here; http://angelaandtom.co.uk/news.html

Can anyone see the error in my code and how I can fix this?

Comment: It shows perfectly fine in my version of Chrome.

Comment: I could see the gradient there. Though this style is not defined for the body but for `#body-news`.

Comment: I guess your browser is loading the stylesheet from it's cache. Clear your cache or hard reload your browser or check in Incognito window.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried reloading and incognito window but it still shows a broken pattern rather than diagonal lines. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you dont set gradiant for `body`**
check css file `http://angelaandtom.co.uk/css/style.css`
you set gradiant for `#body-index` and your `background-size` is `7px`
i've problem with that use below link to set gradient
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
Chrome,Safari4+ use `-webkit-gradient`
Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ use `-webkit-linear-gradient` and use `background`

Comment: I have tried changing it to background but made no difference.

Comment: thanks, i found this site which generates code to make patterns. http://www.patternify.com